# Trying to select rows from different tables

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
select distinct vtw.lastname, vtw.firstname, vtw.dob, vtw.clubnumber, vtw.tournamentname, vtw.BossTournamentID, vtw.tournamentdatetime, vtw.tournamentid, tp.tournamentprizeid, tp.status, tp.place, p.prizeid,p.prizename, tp.bRedeemed, tp.CouponNumber

from vwTournamentWinners vtw, tournamentprizes tp, prizes p

where vtw.fk_tournamentid=tp.fk_tournamentid and vtw.fk_playerid=tp.fk_winnerid and tp.fk_prizeid=p.prizeid and vtw.tournamentdatetime between '8/10/2013' and '8/10/2013' and tp.status='Available'

UNION

SELECT BossID, Status, CouponNumber, FK_PrizeID, FK_WinnerID, PrizeName, FirstName, LastName, DOB 
FROM BountyPrizes, Prizes, Players
where Prizes.PrizeID=BountyPrizes.FK_PrizeID and Players.PlayerID=BountyPrizes.FK_WinnerID

order by vtw.tournamentdatetime DESC
```

Error message:

Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Note: both queries work individually. I want the gridview to display a blank string where the columns cannot be filled in. Chris.

Comment: read the error msg: "All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists" - it doesn't get more specific than that!

Comment: you first and second select is not returning equal number of columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the second select statement to:

```
SELECT BossID, Status, CouponNumber, FK_PrizeID, FK_WinnerID, PrizeName, FirstName, LastName, DOB , '', '' , '', '', '', ''
```

To ensure that both queries return the same amount of fields

Answer (score 0):

select distinct vtw.lastname, vtw.firstname, vtw.dob, vtw.clubnumber, vtw.tournamentname, vtw.BossTournamentID, vtw.tournamentdatetime, vtw.tournamentid, tp.tournamentprizeid, tp.status, tp.place, p.prizeid, p.prizename, tp.bRedeemed, tp.CouponNumber, NULL

from vwTournamentWinners vtw, tournamentprizes tp, prizes p

where vtw.fk_tournamentid=tp.fk_tournamentid and vtw.fk_playerid=tp.fk_winnerid and tp.fk_prizeid=p.prizeid and vtw.tournamentdatetime between '8/10/2013' and '8/10/2013' and tp.status='Available'

UNION

SELECT LastName, FirstName, DOB, NULL, NULL, BossID, NULL, NULL, NULL, Status, NULL, FK_PrizeID,
PrizeName, bRedeemed, CouponNumber, FK_WinnerID

FROM BountyPrizes, Prizes, Players
where Prizes.PrizeID=BountyPrizes.FK_PrizeID and Players.PlayerID=BountyPrizes.FK_WinnerID

order by vtw.tournamentdatetime DESC